# Add variable to the end of each line

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I have a script that prints the date with numbers after it divided by a space " " and saves it into a file, the file is named data.txt and this is his content :

```
21/12/16 18:50 345.44 Mbits/s
21/12/16 18:52 141.59 Mbits/s
21/12/16 18:54 85.52 Mbits/s
```

This is my second script

```
#!/bin/bash

for fn in 'cat data.txt'; do

Speed="$(awk 'BEGIN{FS=" "}{print $3}' Project2.txt)"
example ="this is an example"
done
```

This script is able to extract the numbers "345.44" "141.59" "85.52" from the file. But now I want to add "example" add the end of each line like

```
21/12/16 18:50 345.44 Mbits/s example
21/12/16 18:52 141.59 Mbits/s example
21/12/16 18:54 85.52 Mbits/s example
```

How am i supposed to add the variable to the end of each line? I will continue interacting the variable because i'm making a "chart" but I just need to know how to add the chart to the end of each line in my file.

Comment: Your edit has resulted a different problem to solve. It invalidates the attempts to answer your original question. You should have just asked a new question.

Comment: I edited my answer to reflect your new requirement.

Comment: Sorry for that, the awk was helpfull but I need to know how to add any variable to the end of the same line.

Comment: Your most recent edit destroyed the question. I've rolled it back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=" "}{print $3}' filename
```

FS chooses the field separator which in your case is space
then you choose the field "3"

you can save the output to an array

```
array=$(awk 'BEGIN{FS=" "}{print $3}' filename)
```

then iterate over it.

To add a variable you declare it with in awk using -v option :

```
awk -v var=example 'BEGIN{FS=" "}{print $3 " " var}' filename
```

this will give u

[image]

another way is

```
var='example'

awk  'BEGIN{FS=" "}{print $3   " "  "'"$var"'" }' filename
```

Comment: Thanks , I edited my question can you help me to finish the script?

Comment: Wouldn't you have to surround your awk command with subshell notation like $(awk ...) in order to assign the output to a variable?

Comment: Please [format your code properly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/248777).

Comment: Done,Sorry beginner's mistakes

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F " " '{stars=sprintf("%*s", $3, ""); gsub(//, "*", stars); printf("%s %s\n", $0, stars)}' filename
```

You can perform arithmetic, like division on the $3 to scale the amount of stars you want to see.

Note: with awk, the printf/gsub combination may be the only way to variably repeat a character.

Edit: you changed the requirements of your original question. This is an easier one though.

```
awk -F " " '{printf("%s %d\n", $0, $3)}' filename
```

Edit: since requirements changed once more...

```
awk -F " " '{IntSpeed=sprintf("%d", $3); printf("%s %d\n", $0, IntSpeed)}' filename
```

At this point, you can combine all of these ideas to ultimately make a chart.

Comment: Thanks , I edited my question can you help me to finish the script?

Comment: The format string inside the printf statement takes your floating point speed value in field 3 and displays it as an integer.

Comment: I do not understand where you add the variable $Intspeed to the end of each line. Intspeed is just an example i'm going to continue interacting with this variable until it becomes a chart which i will add to the end of each line.

Comment: With awk, you can just use "$3" as your "IntSpeed"

Comment: But if you really want a named variable you can do IntSpeed=sprintf("%d", $3);

Comment: Sorry for the confusing post. It's not about the "Intspeed" that's just a variable a happen to came up to. I will use the "intspeed in my script to calculate some things. than create a chart that i want to add at the end of the script; the chart simply wil something like chart="xxxxx".

Answer (score 0):

```
#! /bin/bash  
declare -A speed  tab #Associative table

ilg=0
while read line  
do
   set $line  
   speed[$ilg]=$3
   ilg=$(( ilg + 1 ))
done < data.txt

# your calcul 
l=${#speed[@]}  #length of speed
for (( ilg=0; ilg<$l; ilg++ ))
do
  Speed=${speed[$ilg]}
  tab[$ilg]=${Speed%[.]*}
done

ilg=0
while read line  
do
   echo "$line ${tab[$ilg]}"
   ilg=$(( ilg + 1 ))
done < data.txt
```

Test:

```
21/12/16 18:50 345.44 Mbits/s 345
21/12/16 18:52 141.59 Mbits/s 141
21/12/16 18:54 85.52 Mbits/s 85
```

Comment: Thanks , I edited my question can you help me to finish the script?

Comment: @Lewis Algawari Ok, you have to refresh your screen.

Comment: That's quite a long script. Works indeed but I just want to know how to add a variable to the end of a line in my foreach loop. Intspeed is just an example i'm going to continue interacting with this variable until it becomes a chart which i will add to the end of each line.

Comment: @Lewis Algawari, You can carry out average flows and easily add a graph at the end of the line. It's up to you now.